# Since iOS 13 - A lot of app deletions in App Store Connect, can anybody check if this happens with your App as well

Tags: ios, analytics, ios13, app-store-connect

I don´t see any problems like crashes or that the DAU number has changed, but App Store Connect shows 3 times more deletions since the release date of iOS 13. Now I don't know if there is any problem in the App or if Apple has made an upgrade of the "App-Offloading" mechanism? So it would be good to have some feedback, if the app deletion numbers have changed for somebody else as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. In appstoreconnect i see that after September 24, the number of uninstallations increased three times.

Comment: Same problem, same dates. Good question, don't understand why it is downvoted.

Comment: Seeing the same thing as well, happening on the exact same date.

Comment: Same, same.  One theory we had was that iOS 13 is prompting more people to either delete unused apps OR opt-in to data reporting.  But just went through the upgrade myself and didn't see any nudges on either.

Comment: App deletions is a new stat in AppStoreConnect - announced this year at WWDC. Is it that it just wasn't being reported previously, and is now being reported? Or perhaps that it was only iOS13 devices that were reporting it, therefore it increased once iOS13 was released publicly?

Comment: Yes, this is happening with my apps as well. I am seeing major crash problems for other users https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123728 and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122858 - in that particular issue if it's a background problem it could be causing other issues besides crashes which may cause users to delete the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that message in App Store Connect:

> App deletions data was reported incorrectly for iOS and tvOS as of
>   August 2019. This data has been removed from the dashboard for
>   reprocessing and will be re-enabled once reprocessing is done.

See attached screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Low-memory phones are prompted to delete *all* apps before the upgrade.

One of my colleagues has a 6S that is chock-full of photos.  When she upgraded she was told that *all* of her apps would stored in the cloud but deleted on the phone, to make room.  After the upgrade, she still had all the app icons, but those were really just shortcuts to re-download each app anew.

Apparently this also kills notifications, because without the app on the device there's nothing to execute the notification.